# How to get mouse coordinates in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a component triggered with `v-on:click="someMethod"`.

How would I get the mouse coordinates (X, Y) of this click?

Additional information: HTML5 Canvas component

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Vue passes the `event` as the first parameter in the method. If parameters, use this instead: someMethod(param1, param2, event)

```js
    methods: {
        someMethod(event) {
            // clientX/Y gives the coordinates relative to the viewport in CSS pixels.
            console.log(event.clientX);
            console.log(event.clientY);

            // pageX/Y gives the coordinates relative to the <html> element in CSS pixels.
            console.log(event.pageX);
            console.log(event.pageY);

            // screenX/Y gives the coordinates relative to the screen in device pixels.
            console.log(event.screenX);
            console.log(event.screenY);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This works, but if you have parameters in your HTML code, you need to use `$event`.  For example: `<canvas @click="someMethod(param1, param2, $event)">`

You can then create `someMethod(param1, param2, event)` in your `methods` section.

Answer (score 6):

Like you would in any event handler

```
new Vue({
  el: '#element',
  methods: {
    someMethod: function (event) {
      var x = event.pageX;
      var y = event.pageY;
    }
  }
})
```

There's also `clientX` and `screenX`, they return somewhat different results based on the viewport, the screen or the rendered content.